# AfterDeleteEvent from AbstractMongoEventListener is not being triggered when entry is deleted from MongoDb

Tags: java, database, mongodb, triggers, event-listener

I have a class that extends `AbstractMongoEventListener` and overrides `onAfterSave` and `onAfterDelete`.

The `onAfterDelete` does not trigger for some reason. The `onAfterSave` works fine.
Is there a different configuration that needs to be done for it?

```
public class ClassX extends AbstractMongoEventListener<DomainClass> {
    @Override
    public void onAfterSave(AfterSaveEvent<DomainClass> event) {
        //dosomething
    }

    @Override
    public void onAfterDelete(AfterDeleteEvent<DomainClass> event) {
        //dosomething
    }
}
```

I have already checked the database and the data is being properly deleted, but the onAfterDelete still don't get called.

Any suggestion of what could be the problem?

The repository:

```
public interface DomainClassRepository extends MongoRepository<DomainClass, String> {
}
```

I'm calling the method `DomainClassRepository.delete(instanceOfDomainClass)` to delete the entry in the db.

Answer (score 1):

##### Short answer:

Mongo events could be triggered with typed queries only.

I've tried `spring-data-mongodb-2.2.8` version, it handles `DomainClassRepository.delete(instanceOfDomainClass)` and `DomainClassRepository.deleteById(idOfDomainClass)` properly.

Method `onAfterDelete` can't be triggered when `DomainClassRepository.deleteAll()`  is called because it's untyped.

##### Long answer (Research):

Check `onApplicationEvent` method in `AbstractMongoEventListener`.
It contains this code block:

```
if (event instanceof AbstractDeleteEvent) {

        Class<?> eventDomainType = ((AbstractDeleteEvent) event).getType();

        if (eventDomainType != null && domainClass.isAssignableFrom(eventDomainType)) {
            if (event instanceof BeforeDeleteEvent) {
                onBeforeDelete((BeforeDeleteEvent<E>) event);
            }
            if (event instanceof AfterDeleteEvent) {
                onAfterDelete((AfterDeleteEvent<E>) event);
            }
        }

        return;

}
```

And check `AbstractDeleteEvent` under package `org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.mapping.event`. Constructor allows to have nullable type:

```
/**
 * Creates a new {@link AbstractDeleteEvent} for the given {@link Document} and type.
 *
 * @param document must not be {@literal null}.
 * @param type may be {@literal null}.
 * @param collectionName must not be {@literal null}.
 * @since 1.8
 */
public AbstractDeleteEvent(Document document, @Nullable Class<T> type, String collectionName) {

    super(document, document, collectionName);
    this.type = type;
}
```